# How to update H2O cluster version on R with MacOS?

Tags: r, h2o

Whenever I import `h2o` from R on my Mac, I see a warning message

```
Your H2O cluster version is too old (8 months and 2 days)!
Please download and install the latest version from http://h2o.ai/download/
```

So I followed the installation guide from h2o homepage(http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-zipf/3/index.html) by running

```
# The following two commands remove any previously installed H2O packages for R.
if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) { detach("package:h2o", unload=TRUE) }
if ("h2o" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) { remove.packages("h2o") }

# Next, we download packages that H2O depends on.
pkgs <- c("RCurl","jsonlite")
for (pkg in pkgs) {
if (! (pkg %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages(pkg) }
}

# Now we download, install and initialize the H2O package for R.
install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos="http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-zipf/3/R")
```

But this approach does not solve the problem but generates error.

```
R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:         10 days 3 hours 
    H2O cluster timezone:       America/New_York 
    H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC 
    H2O cluster version:        3.32.0.1 
    H2O cluster version age:    8 months and 2 days !!! 
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_matthewson_gtl621 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
    H2O cluster total memory:   25.55 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    8 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  8 
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
    H2O Connection port:        54321 
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
    H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
    H2O API Extensions:         Amazon S3, XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, TargetEncoder, Core V4 
    R Version:                  R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) 

Error in h2o.init() : 
  Version mismatch! H2O is running version 3.32.0.1 but h2o-R package is version 3.32.1.3.
         Install the matching h2o-R version from - https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-zermelo/1/index.html
In addition: Warning message:
In h2o.clusterInfo() : 
Your H2O cluster version is too old (8 months and 2 days)!
Please download and install the latest version from http://h2o.ai/download/
```

Is there a way to update cluster's h2o version? I'm not experiencing this issue on windows machine though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems h2o cluster version is updated on CRAN version now. Simply reinstalling from CRAN solved the issue.